# Laravel multiple authentication from two different route and view

Tags: laravel, authentication, authorization, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I want to implement a system where 6 types of users exist. So one is 'customer' who will login by a route like `/login` and rest of 5 users are admins and only they will be login using another route `/system/base-admin`. However, 'customer' never login with the `/system/base-admin` route if anyhow can known this route. And both route have different login form and if they failed to login 'customer' will be redirected `/login` and admins `/system/base-admin`.

I know about $guard and middleware check.

**Question:** How can i implement above scenario and  how react professionals with this scenario?

```
Route::get('/login','CustomerLoginController@processLogin')->name('customer.login');


Route::get('/system/base-admin', 'AdminLoginController@processAdminLogin')->name('system.admin')
```

My Controller Looks like

```
public function processLogin(){ return view('customer.login');}

public function processAdminLogin(){ return view('admin.login')}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I see to have different endpoints for login is to have different views.
Copy your `Auth\LoginController`, change `$redirectTo` to redirect to your admin panel. Overwrite `AuthenticatesUsers\showLoginForm` to show your admin form and update middleware in `__construct`.
Protect all your admin routes with admin middleware.

Now. Your users CAN login to your panel. BUT nothing will happen since they don't have access.

If you want to show them some kind of message when they try you can overwrite `AuthenticatesUsers\login` method with something like this

```
...
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            if(!auth()->user()->isAdmin()){
               throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                 $this->username() => 'You don\'t have access to this page',
               ]);
            }
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
...
```